# How to optimize big table read and outer join in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, outer-join

I am joining a big table with 3 other tables,

A = join small table by  (f1,f2) RIGHT OUTER  ,  massiveTable by (f1,f2) ;

B = join AnotherSmall by  (f3) RIGHT OUTER  , A by (f3) ;

C = join AnotherSmall by  (f4) , B by (f4) ;

The small tables may not fit in memory, but this forces a billion object read three times and time consuming, I was wondering if there is any way rereading can be avoided and process can be made more efficient?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is `f3` and `f4` from the "massiveTable" or the original small table?

Comment: They are part massive table. Practically we are denormalizing data

Answer (score 0):

If you design your big table in HBase to have three column families, i.e. splitting `f1` and `f2`, from `f3` and from `f4`, you should be able to avoid the unnecessary reads.

Also if you think about it, you don't re-read but rather read a different part of a record: firstly `f1` and `f2`, then `f3` and finally `f4`.